# XNA 4.0 Game Development by example a beginners guide

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, xna-4.0

I am following along in the book *XNA 4.0 Game Development By Example:  A Beginner's Guide* and I keep getting a Null Reference Exception error.  Specifically on the `game.Tick` section of my code. Just wondering if I am coding incorrectly or if Visual Studio is just acting strange.
Thanks

```
namespace Level_Editor
{
    public partial class MapEditor : Form
    {
        public Game1 game;


        public MapEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoadImageList()
        {
            string filepath = Application.StartupPath +
                @"\Content\Textures\PlatformTiles.png";
            Bitmap tileSheet = new Bitmap(filepath);
            int tilecount = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < tileSheet.Height / TileMap.TileHeight; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < tileSheet.Width / TileMap.TileWidth; x++)
                {
                    Bitmap newBitmap = tileSheet.Clone(new
                        System.Drawing.Rectangle(
                            x * TileMap.TileWidth,
                            y * TileMap.TileHeight,
                            TileMap.TileWidth,
                            TileMap.TileHeight),
                            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);

                    imgListTiles.Images.Add(newBitmap);
                    string itemName = "";
                    if (tilecount == 0)
                    {
                        itemName = "Empty";
                    }
                    if (tilecount == 1)
                    {
                        itemName = "White";
                    }
                    listTiles.Items.Add(new
                        ListViewItem(itemName, tilecount++));
                }
            }

            FixScrollBarScales();
        }

        private void FixScrollBarScales()
        {
            Camera.ViewPortWidth = pctSurface.Width;
            Camera.ViewPortHeight = pctSurface.Height;

            Camera.Move(Vector2.Zero);

            vScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
            vScrollBar1.Maximum =
                Camera.WorldRectangle.Height -
                Camera.ViewPortHeight;

            hScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
            hScrollBar1.Maximum =
                Camera.WorldRectangle.Width -
                Camera.ViewPortWidth;
        }

        private void loadMapToolStripMenuItem_Click(
            object sender,
            EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                TileMap.LoadMap(new FileStream(
                    Application.StartupPath + @"\MAP" +
                    cboMapNumber.Items[cboMapNumber.SelectedIndex] + ".MAP",
                    FileMode.Open));
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Unable to load map file");
            }
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           game.Exit();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void MapEditor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadImageList();

            cboCodeValues.Items.Clear();
            cboCodeValues.Items.Add("Gemstone");
            cboCodeValues.Items.Add("Enemy");
            cboCodeValues.Items.Add("Lethal");
            cboCodeValues.Items.Add("EnemyBlocking");
            cboCodeValues.Items.Add("Start");
            cboCodeValues.Items.Add("Clear");
            cboCodeValues.Items.Add("Custom");

            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                cboMapNumber.Items.Add(x.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0'));
            }

            cboMapNumber.SelectedIndex = 0;

            TileMap.EditorMode = true;

            backgroundToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
        }

        private void timerGameUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (hScrollBar1.Maximum < 0)
            {
                FixScrollBarScales();
            }

            game.Tick();

            if (game== null && game.HoverCodeValue != lblCurrentCode.Text)
               lblCurrentCode.Text =game.HoverCodeValue;

        }

        private void MapEditor_FormClosed(
            object sender,
            FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
           game.Exit();
            Application.Exit();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any initialisation of the `Game1 game` object.

Comment: So I would initialize the Game1 game object right underneath public MapEditor() ?  I'm just confused because I'm following the book word for word.

Comment: Why do you have a `Game1` object in your class? `Game1` is only the main class that runs your game, what you probably want is a `Game` object.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, it seems that you haven't initialized the "game" object. I know a Game class object is defined in your main class and starting point of the program but, it seems that you haven't passed a reference to it in your MapEditor class.

Here, the program thinks that you have defined a new Game object but, have not initialized it. That's why it's spitting out a Null Reference Exception. You need to reference your original game object in this class, either by passing it, or through usage of global variables.

Comment: Hmm... Didn't you already instantiate it in the main class of your program? If so, just pass a reference to it into this class. Otherwise, do it in the constructor (though it may cause some issues here, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

In your `MapEditor` constructor you need to initialize your `Game1` object, but I suggest you to use `Game` instead of `Game1`, because `Game1` is the main class that runs your game and you should not use it in that way.

Try something like this:

```
public Game game;

public MapEditor(Game game)
{
    this.game = game;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```